# $\dfrac{1}{10!} = a, \space \space 1+ \dfrac{1}{10! + 11!}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

$$\dfrac{1}{10!} = a, \space \space 1+  \dfrac{1}{10! + 11!}$$

It wants me to evaluate this expression in terms of $a$. Let me show my work as illustrated below

$$ 1+  \dfrac{1}{10! + 11!}$$

After factoring we get

$$\dfrac{1}{10!} \biggr( 1+ \dfrac{1}{11}\biggr ) + 1$$

I couldn't proceed further. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

from $\dfrac{1}{10!} = a$, can we can conclude that $\dfrac{1}{a} = 10!$.

Use this to see that:

$$1 + \dfrac{1}{10! + 11!} = 1 + \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{a} + 11!}$$

$$=1 +\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{a} + \dfrac{11!a}{a}}$$
$$=1 +\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1+11!a}{a}}$$
$$=1 +\dfrac{a}{1+11!a}$$
$$=1 +\dfrac{a}{1+11!\cdot\dfrac{1}{10!}}$$
$$=1 +\dfrac{a}{12}$$

Can you go on from here?

Answer (score 1):

Given $$\dfrac{1}{10!} = a$$

$$1+  \dfrac{1}{10! + 11!}$$
$$1+  \dfrac{1}{10! + 11\cdot 10!}$$
$$1+  \dfrac{1}{10!(12)}$$
$$1+  \dfrac{a}{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

No, it should be $1+a/12$ because $(10!+11!)/10!=1+11=12$.